# How do i execute a stored procedure using a data dictionary link in ADS?

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I have a stored procedure in data dictionary A and i would like to execute it from data dictionary B using a Link. I tried the following syntax but it didnt work :

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE A.PROC()
```

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance.